# how to add a nav spacer in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am creating a Nav menu using Twitter Bootstrap.

In the design there are spacers between menus. So if I add border-right it looks ok! but when viewing in phone or smaller viewport I want that border-right to become border-bottom in collapsed menu.

How can i achieve this using Boostrap?

Bigger Viewport:

[image: bigger viewport]

Smaller Viewport:
[image: smaller viewport]

Comment: Post the code for your nav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `divider-horizontal` and `divider-vertical` classes are used to create separation/spacers between menus.

You can either use these or customise these classes to your requirements.  See the examples usage at - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs.

Note: This requires additional markup, an `li` element with the required class.